# Can I use user's environment variables in visual studio command line arguments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, environment-variables

Say I have user's environment variable named `Version`. I want to use it in command line arguments when i run my C# program. So I tried something like `%Version%` or `$(Version)` but program takes it like a regular string. So is it possible to use environment variables like this? And what is the syntax in this case?

UPD: I want to pass variable using exactly command line arguments in visual studio.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without change to your code, just in the VS GUI: no.

In your code you could call [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-2.2#System_Environment_ExpandEnvironmentVariables_System_String_) on each argument in turn.

This replaces `%xyz%` with the value of environment variable `xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I did not misunderstand your question.

#### Case 1: You mean "inside my program"

See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8

You can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to read such a variable.

#### Case 2: You mean "supply it as parameter"

In this case, `%Version%` is fine, as long as you defined it in the system and not "just in another cmd window".
To define a global environment variable:

- Open System by pressing WIN+Pause
- On the left click on "Advanced system settings"
- A popup window "System properties" opens. Bottom right you find a "Environment variables" Button -> *click*
- Another window opens where you see your personal variables on top and system-wide variables in the bottom half (this is, where your "path" and other things are set)
- Enter your Version variable there and you can access it via the `args` in the `main`

You get the value in your program in your

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
     //args[0] contains the first argument, args[1] the second and so on
     // Find the number of arguments with args.Length
}
```

Comment: I added the update, hope it helps to clarify my question

Comment: So this is case 2 then. But keep in mind: You must set the variable in Windows - not in a cmd-shell!! If you just set it in a command shell then the variable is only known to this shell window. I will update my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: I set my user's env var from visual studio extension using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer directly to your question but instead a suggestion to solve your problem differently. 
Use the [#if directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) so the environment variable reading will compile only if you have a debug build.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string version = "release_version";
    #if DEBUG
    version = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Version");
    #endif

    new Program(version);
}
```